# Should I set "Ignore" cookie headers flagged from Akamai WAF or change its severity to Informational?

Tags: cookies, waf, header

I've been seeing our AppScan tools tagging cookie headers from Akamai in low severity.
Mostly tagged as missing attributes of "HTTPOnly" and "Secure" flag.

The question here is should I fully ignore those flagged issues as these are false positives? or should I set the issue "Informational"? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not set the recommend cookie flags? Is the target app setting them?

Comment: Currently, doing regex test to ignore WAF cookie headers in Qualys WAS. The appscan always tagged the cookie header as an issue.